# Does adding Yosemite Tags to a File change its MD5 Signature?

Tags: finder-tag

I have a cloud backup system that relies on MD5 hash signatures for de-duplication.

Does adding OSX tags to a file change its MD5 hash?

EDIT: I did some testing and got mixed results depending on the filetype/app used. So not sure if the tag itself is making a difference or something else change by the app.

Comment: Did you try it with a sample file and tag?

Comment: Would have taken about 15 seconds to test… no, makes no difference, neither does changing the name.

Comment: I don't know how to do a controlled test. I did try a .txt file and it made no difference, however on a PDF file it did change, so I am not sure if it is because of the tag itself or something else that the preview app changes on the PDF file.

Comment: How did you add the tag?

Comment: By clicking on the file name in the titlebar.

Answer (score 2):

I ran **md5 *file*** in Terminal.app, applied a tag to *file*, and re-ran **md5**. The hash returned was the same. Without knowing your exact setup it's impossible to know for sure, but it looks like you're OK.

Answer (score 2):

One thing I thought of that might affect the outcome is *which* tags you're adding, and how. The traditional label colors (Red, Orange, ...) are stored in a 3-bit subfield of the FinderInfo field of the HFS+ catalog record for the file. The new labels are stored instead in an *extended attribute* of the file.

Under the new scheme, if Finder sets the tag, it always puts it (or them) in the `com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags` extended attribute. If some other application sets the label index, for example with the AppleScript command

```
tell application "Finder" to set label index of someFile to 3
```

the label index is set in FinderInfo. A non-zero value for FinderInfo causes the `xattr` command to list it *as if* it were the extended attribute `com.apple.FinderInfo`, where you can see the label index as three of the bits in the tenth byte. The interaction between these two fields is complex. Sometimes modifying one will clear the other, sometimes not.

`md5` might be affected differently depending on what metadata, if any, is included in the checksum versus which metadata is affected by the method you use to set the label.

The good news is that `md5` appears to ignore all metadata. It computes a checksum of only the data fork. It doesn't even incorporate the resource fork. (To checksum the resource fork, you have to explicitly ask for it, as in `md5 "Icon^M"/..namedfork/rsrc`, but then the resource fork is the *only* thing it looks at.)

Comment: That would, imo, be the sensible thing for it to do - the resource fork wouldn't necessarily make it over to another machine, so would almost randomly appear to break checksums, otherwise.